# Big Endian and Little endian little confusion

Tags: c, pointers, endianness

I was reading about little and big endian representations from this site http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/little-and-big-endian-mystery/.

Suppose we have a number 0x01234567, then in little endian it is stored as (67)(45)(23)(01) and in Big endian it is stored as (01)(23)(45)(67).

```
char *s= "ABCDEF"
int *p = (int *)s;
printf("%d",*(p+1)); // prints 17475 (value of DC)
```

After seeing the printed value here in the above code, it seems that string is stored as (BA)(DC)(FE).

Why is it not stored like (EF)(CD)(AB) from LSB to MSB as in first example? I thought that endianess means ordering of bytes within multi-bytes. So the ordering should be with respect to "whole 2 bytes" as in 2nd case and not within those 2 bytes right?

Comment: "After seeing the printed value here in the above code," — What printed value?  On my little-endian machine, the given code prints `17989` (hex: `0x4645`), which seems perfectly normal to me.

Comment: this looks like UB to me. `s` points to 6 bytes. you equate `p` to `s`, but when you print you do `p+1`. Assuming you have 4 byte `int`s, this will point `p` to `'E'`. The next byte is `'F'`, and then the next 2 bytes are beyond your allocated space. But that aside, looks good to me, my little endian printout is 0x25004645. 0x45 is `'E'`, 0x46 is `'F'`, and 0x00 and 0x25 are no man's land.

Comment: @yano,  My compiler considers CD as "DC". I have 2 byte ints. See my edit.

Comment: ok,, with 2 byte `int`'s (`short`s on my machine), forget the UB, still looks good. My printout now is 0x4443, where 0x43 is `'C'` and 0x44 is '`D'`. I suspect you're confusing string ASCII characters with hex values? Each character in your string corresponds to a byte, which can be represented with a 2 digit hex number. Use the `printf` format specifier `"%x"` to print in hex. 17475 is indeed 0x4443, which is what is expected from a little endian machine.

Comment: Yes, but I do not understand why is it represented as (BA)(DC)(FE) instead of (EF)(CD)(AB).

Comment: you're still using Turbo C? let it die ASAP

Comment: `"ABCDEF"` and `0xABCDEF` are very different...

Comment: my first comment was a bit erroneous. Strings in `c` are `NUL` terminated of course, so the `'\0'` byte at the end is part of the string and accessing it is perfectly legal. Only the 0x25 is no man's land.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Working with 2 byte `int`s, this is what you have in memory

```
memAddr  |  0  |  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |  5  |  6   |
data     | 'A' | 'B' | 'C' | 'D' | 'E' | 'F' | '\0' |
            ^ s points here
                        ^ p+1 points here
```

Now, it looks like you're using ASCII encoding, so this is what you *really* have in memory

```
memAddr  |  0   |  1   |  2   |  3   |  4   |  5   |  6   |
data     | 0x41 | 0x42 | 0x43 | 0x44 | 0x45 | 0x46 | 0x00 |
            ^ s points here
                          ^ p+1 points here
```

So for a little endian machine, that means the least significant bytes **for a multi-byte type** come first. There's no concept of endianess for a single byte `char`.  An ASCII string is just a string of `char`s.. this has no endianess.  Your `int`s are 2 bytes.  So for an `int` starting at memory location 2, this byte is the least significant, and the one at address 3 is the most significant.  This means the number here, read the way people generally read numbers, is 0x4443 (17475 in base 10, "DC" as an ASCII string), since 0x44 in memory location 3 is more significant than 0x43 in memory location 2.  For big endian, of course, this would be reversed, and the number would be 0x4344 (17220 in base 10, "CD" as an ASCII string).

EDIT:

Addressing your comment... A `c` string is a `NUL` terminated array of `char`s, that's absolutely correct. Endianess only applies to the primitive types, `short, int, long, long long`, etc. ("primitive types" may be incorrect nomenclature, someone who knows can correct me).  An array is simply a section of contiguous memory where 1 or more types occur directly next to each other, stored *sequentially*. There is no concept of endianess for the entire array, however, endianess *does* apply to the primitive types of the individual elements of the array.  Let's say you have the following, assume 2 byte `int`s:

```
int array[3];  // with 2 byte ints, this occupies 6 contiguous bytes in memory
array[0] = 0x1234;
array[1] = 0x5678;
array[2] = 0x9abc;
```

This is what memory looks like:  It will look like this no matter for a big or little endian machine

```
memAddr   |    0-1   |    2-3   |    4-5   |
data      | array[0] | array[1] | array[2] |
```

Notice there is no concept of endianess for the array *elements*. This is true no matter what the elements are.  The elements could be primitive types, `structs`,, anything.  The first element in the array is always at `array[0]`.

But now, if we look at the what's actually in the array, this is where endianess does come into play.  For a little endian machine, memory will look like this:

```
memAddr   |  0   |  1   |  2   |  3   |  4   |  5   |
data      | 0x34 | 0x12 | 0x78 | 0x56 | 0xbc | 0x9a |
             ^______^      ^______^      ^______^
             array[0]      array[1]      array[2]
```

The least significant bytes are first.  A big endian machine would look like this:

```
memAddr   |  0   |  1   |  2   |  3   |  4   |  5   |
data      | 0x12 | 0x34 | 0x56 | 0x78 | 0x9a | 0xbc |
             ^______^      ^______^      ^______^
             array[0]      array[1]      array[2]
```

Notice the *contents* of each element of the array is subject to endianess (because it's an array of primitive types.. if it was an array of `structs`, the `struct` members wouldn't subject to some kind of endianess reversal,, endianess only applies to primitives). However, whether on the big or little endian machine, the array elements are still in the same order.

Getting back to your string, a string is simply a `NUL` terminated array of characters.  `char`s are single bytes, so there's only one way to order them.  Consider the code:

```
char word[] = "hey";
```

This is what you have in memory:

```
memAddr   |    0    |    1    |    2    |    3    |
data      | word[0] | word[1] | word[2] | word[3] |
                  equals NUL terminator '\0' ^
```

Just in this case, each element of the `word` array is a single byte, and there's only one way to order a single item, so whether on a little or big endian machine, this is what you'll have in memory:

```
memAddr   |  0   |  1   |  2   |  3   |
data      | 0x68 | 0x65 | 0x79 | 0x00 |
```

Endianess only applies to multi-byte primitive types.  I highly recommend poking around in a debugger to see this in live action.  All the popular IDEs have memory view windows, or with `gdb` you can [print out memory](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_56.html).  In `gdb` you can print memory as bytes, halfwords (2 bytes), words (4 bytes), giant words (8 bytes), etc.  On a little endian machine, if you print out your string as bytes, you'll see the letters in order.  Print out as halfwords, you'll see every 2 letters "reversed", print out as words, every 4 letters "reversed", etc.  On a big endian machine, it would all print out in the same "readable" order.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. String is an array of bytes or multi-byte right ? So why are characters (single byte) not stored in reverse as it is a part of a string which is multi-byte?

Comment: Best  descriptive  and  thorough  description of  endianness, and the  distinction between big endian and small endian.  Great  work

Answer (score 3):

**<sup>*2022 edit*</sup>**

The processor doesn't know what kind of data it is dealing with, text or number. Everything is numbers in memory.

<sup>(special CPU instructions deal with floating point numbers that expect the 4 / 8 ... bytes to fit some standard, but anyway in memory they're just 8-bits bytes which value goes from 0 to 255, like everything else)</sup>

Conventionally

```
the letter 'A' is represented by the hex number 0x41 (65 decimal)
...     
the letter 'F' is represented by the hex number 0x46 (70 decimal)
```

and the text "ABCDEF" appears in memory (in hex) as (in C the compiler adds a byte 0 after the 'F')

```
----- addresses ----->
|41|42|43|44|45|46|00|
----------------------
```

On a 2-bytes `int` little-endian system, reading at `p+1` (your example) in a `i` variable,

```
---- addresses --->
|41|42|43|44|45|46|
|p + 0|p + 1|p + 2|        
-------------------
```

since it's a little-endian system `i` value is

```
 0x4443 (17475 in decimal, the value you saw)
```

The first byte read is the least significant byte of an `int` (0x43) and the next is the most (MSB, 0x44).

Note that on a big-endian system it would be

```
 0x4344 (17220 in decimal)
```

Now maybe you meant to store the number `0xABCDEF` (hex, 11259375 decimal) in memory. We need at least a 32-bits int to store that value in a variable ; say your compiler `long` type has 32 bits.

```
long l = 0xABCDEF;
```

in memory (little endian) the number is stored like this

```
------------>
|EF|CD|AB|00|
-------------
```

Note that there is also a "trailing" 0, but in this case it is the MSB of that number being 0 on 32 bits.

In this case you find the (EF)(CD)(AB) you expected, because the compiler treated the code word 0xABCDEF as a number. In the other case, the compiler treated the text "ABCDEF" as it is, a string of chars.

---

**<sup>*2017 original answer*</sup>**

It seems there is a little confusion between the string of characters

```
1)  "ABCDEF"
```

and the number 11,259,375 which expressed in hexadecimal is

```
2)  0xABCDEF
```

In the first case, each letter takes a whole byte.
In the second case, we have six hexadecimal digits ; one hex digit takes 4 bits, so two digits are needed in a byte.

*Endianness* wise, in case

1. characters 'A', then 'B' etc.. are written sequentially in memory. 'A' is 0x41, 'B' 0x42... In case
2. this is a multi bytes integer which byte-order depends on architecture. Say the number is 4 bytes, a big-endian arc would store in memory (hex) 00 AB CD EF ; little-endian will store in this order: EF CD AB 00

Big endian

```
A  B  C  D  E  F
41 42 43 44 45 46   [ text ]
00 AB CD EF         [ integer ] 
----(addresses)---->
```

Little endian

```
----(addresses)---->
A  B  C  D  E  F
41 42 43 44 45 46   [ text ]
EF CD AB 00         [ integer ]
```

In your case

```
char *s= "ABCDEF";     // text
int *p = (int *)s;     //
printf("%d",*(p+1));   // *(p+1) is p[1]
```

since your implementation has `sizeof(int) == 2`, the number printed (17475) is 0x4443, or 'DC' (characters), having `0x44` ('D') as the MSB and `0x43` ('C') as LSB shows that your architecture is little-endian.

Writing a string of chars (sequentially) in memory and reading a couple of them as an `int` gives a number that depends on endianness. Yes, **endianness matters** in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. String is an array of bytes or multi-byte right ? So why are characters (single byte) not stored in reverse as it is a part of a string which is multi-byte?

Comment: Strings are made of characters, sometimes a lot, and characters are stored sequentially - there is no reason to do otherwise, and that would be even problematic. The reason integers (numbers) are stored based on architecture is due to the mapping between the CPU / registers and memory, and this is due to a choice made by the manufacturer - see [advantages of each arc](https://thebittheories.com/little-endian-vs-big-endian-b4046c63e1f2)

Comment: Yeah, got it ! Thanks !!

Comment: Should have said an important point: "numbers" are of fixed size, strings are not (far from it!). One more reason that allows a special treatment for int, float, ...

Comment: So in memory it is **actually** stored as ABCDEF (in this order only) as it is a char array. But just because we use an int pointer to access char array, the 2 bytes when dereferenced get **interpreted** differently right?

Answer (score 1):

Endianness doesn't come into play when talking about storing bytes as in the char const  array that is pointed to by `s`. If you examined the memory at `*s` you would find the bytes `'a'`, `'b'`, `'c'` ..., when interpreted as an `int` on a little endian system however it would get interpreted as `"DCBA"`.

Remember that each `char` is already a byte, if you had `char const * s = "0xfedcab09";` and you did a `printf("%d", *(int const *)s);` on a little endian system then it would print as whatever 0x9abcdef comes out as in decimal.

Answer (score 0):

The confusion presented here is due to *notation*.

The *string* “ABCDEF” can be interpreted (and stored) multiple ways.

In a ***character string*** each letter takes an entire byte (`char`).

```
char s[] = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 0 };
```

However, the hexadecimal representation of the ***number*** ABCDEF is different, each digit ('0'..'9' and 'A'..'F') represents only four bits, or half a byte. Thus, the *number* `0xABCDEF` is the sequence of bytes

```
0xAB 0xCD 0xEF
```

This is where *endianness* becomes an issue:

- Little Endian: least significant byte first
   `int x = { 0xEF, 0xCD, 0xAB };`
- Big Endian: most significant byte first
   `int x = { 0xAB, 0xCD, 0xEF }`
- Mixed Endian: <other random orderings>
   `int x = { 0xEF, 0x00, 0xCD, 0xAB }`